# How to rewrite CSS rules on tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js, tailwind-3

I have the following styles in figma:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
padding: 10px 16px;

position: absolute;
width: 227px;
height: 40px;

/* Button/Red */

background: #E30513;
/* RedBtn */

box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px rgba(157, 84, 81, 0.44);
border-radius: 10px;
```

I tried to rewrite these styles on tailwind for the buttion:

```
  <button type="submit" class="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-xl shadow-sm text-white bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-600 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2">Make request</button>
```

But I have faced with problems:

- There is no tailwind `border-radius: 10px` only `rounded-lg` or `rounded-xl`.
- There is no `padding: 10px 16px;` only [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding)
- No the same shadow
- No color #E30513

Could you explain me, how to use tailwind in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it directly from `tailwind` classes using [Arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<button 
type="submit" 
class="flex flex-row items-center py-[10px] px-[16px]
       absolute w-[227px] h-[40px] bg-[#E30513]
        shadow-[0px_4px_12px_rgba(157,84,81,0.44)]
        rounded-[10px] 
      ">

  Make request
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! How to be if design has different padding, height, fontsize of inputs. So I need to get the same input like in design. But Tailwind provides different values for that. Should I create own class for each input? What is benefit then if I use Tailwind?

Comment: Also it is good to use px instead rem ?

Comment: @AliceMessis if you are planning to reuse those classes then you may need to specify and add them to `tailwind.config.js` so you can access them easily and also this way you will have many different options

Comment: @AliceMessis it's better to use `rem` because it's a relative unit related to the root font sizes(the r in rem actually stands for root)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to solve this problem.

Tailwind CSS v3 actually supports setting arbitrary values.

- `border-radius: 10px` can be represented as `rounded-[10px]`
- `padding: 10px 16px` can be represented as `py-[10px] px-[16px]`
- `box-shadow: 0px 4px 12px rgba(157, 84, 81, 0.44)` can be represented as `shadow-[0px_4px_12px_rgba(157,84,81,0.44)]`
- `background: #E30513` can be represented as `bg-[#E30513]`

Here's an example of your button: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9K23furBKo

Alternatively, if you plan to use these values more than once, you could also easily extend your Tailwind CSS configuration.

Here are the links to the relevant documentation pages:

- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-radius#using-custom-values
- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/padding#using-custom-values
- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow#using-custom-values
- https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#using-custom-values

Comment: Thank you! So is it good to use px instead rem? Here: `py-[10px] px-[16px]`?

Comment: I can not get if there are sizes in figma temaplte, shoudl I set the same sizes in tailwind or not?

Comment: Could you share an tutorial how to customize own buttons and make it as kit?